# Remove selected feature Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openlayers 3 to create web application that allow to user to draw LineString features in the map.
this is the code:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'sat' })
});


var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    name: 'my_vectorlayer',
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 5
        })
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View2D({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })

});
var draw;
function addInteraction() {
 map.removeInteraction(singleClick);
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: ("LineString")
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
}
```

by the previous code i can drow lines in to the map. the drawn lines will be added to  `vector` layer. I wont when the user select one of the line that he draw can remove them.
this is the code of selecting the feature:

```
var singleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
function addSelect() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    map.addInteraction(singleClick);
}
```

and it's work very will, [image]

I just want the user to be able to remove the selected LineString...

Comment: Hi, I edit the question up there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can remove selected feature.

```
var draw;
var featureID = 0;
var singleClick;
var selectedFeatureID;

// First some change in this function.

function addInteraction() {
   map.removeInteraction(singleClick);

      draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: ("LineString")
  });

 // Create drawend event of feature and set ID to feature

  draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
    featureID = featureID + 1;
    event.feature.setProperties({
        'id': featureID
    })
 })
   map.addInteraction(draw);
 }
```

Then Change in select Function as follow:

```
 function addSelect() {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    singleClick = new ol.interaction.Select();
    map.addInteraction(singleClick);

     singleClick .getFeatures().on('add', function (event) {
     var properties = event.element.getProperties();
     selectedFeatureID = properties.id;       
    });
 }
```

Then call this function on REMOVE button click

```
 function removeSelectedFeature() {
   var features = source.getFeatures();
     if (features != null && features.length > 0) {
         for (x in features) {
            var properties = features[x].getProperties();
            console.log(properties);
            var id = properties.id;
            if (id == selectedFeatureID) {
              source.removeFeature(features[x]);
               break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

With this code you can remove any selected feature. If it is Line,Point, Polygon etc.

Comment: You should set feature id with [`feature.setId(id)`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setId) and get with `feature.getId()`

Answer (score 0):

First, if you could give me some more details, I could better help you answer your question. I don't think I fully understand what you are asking. Here are a couple of possibilities.

1) The simple but limited solution is just to use a layer switcher. Something like [this](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher). Assuming you are using a wms like geoserver, you can use SQL-like views to make a bunch of layers you can add or remove. If you need to do something simple like this, I can edit the answer to provide more details.

2) I haven't done this before, but this might be something to look [into](http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/). Basically, you will use ol.format.wfs to select and delete features.

Comment: I will need the first solution in other level in my project, so if you provide some details it's will be great :)